# Buildind NDK static library

Tags: android, android-ndk

I'm trying to build a static library for distribution (I don't have an app) using NDK. Here's my Android.mk file:

```
MY_HOMEDIR = $(shell pwd)
MY_SRCDIR = src
MY_SOURCES = $(shell find $(MY_SRCDIR) -type f -name "*.cpp")

LOCAL_PATH = $(MY_HOMEDIR)
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE = prj
LOCAL_SRC_FILES = $(MY_SOURCES)
TARGET_PLATFORM = android-16
TARGET_ARCH_ABI = all
LOCAL_CPP_FEATURES = exceptions

include $(BUILD_STATIC_LIBRARY)
```

It seems to be building properly (I haven't tested it on a project yet). Here's the output it generates:

```
+ libs
  + armeabi
    gdb.setup
    gdb.server
+ obj
  + local
    + armeabi
      + objs-debug (a bunch of .o files here)
      libprj.a
```

Is this only building for the armeabi architecture? I specified `all` for the `TARGET_ARCH_ABI` setting, but it doesn't seem to be working, or at least it's not generating folders for other architectures.

Comment: Try setting `APP_ABI := all` in your Application.mk instead.

Comment: Same result, it didn't work =\

Comment: Call the build with `ndk-build -B V=1` and see the logs.

Comment: Oh, forgot that I still had this question open. I'll post the answer. Thank you anyway

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realised I was missing the `Application.mk` file. I assumed that I didn't need it because I'm building a library, but it's still needed. In that file include the following:

```
APP_ABI = all
```

Problem solved.
Best.